# Angular js web application- offline authentication and persistence

Tags: angularjs, offlineapps

We have an angular js application application developed on Sails framework and uses mysql for persistence. The website is authenticated using Active Directory credentials. 
Now we would like to enhance the app to work offline as well. So the following questions arise.

1. How should we accomplish Active Directory authentication while accessing the app offline?
2. As I can understand that Indexeddb or Pouchdb can be considered for offline persistence, which one between the two would be better or is there any other better alternative and how can we sync data from offline storage to online persistence which is on mysql?

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

offline web application may not contain all online applicability.

for example; authenticating a user in a large system, need an online connection to server and its not possible and very stupidly idea to save hash of all password in client offline storage.

so you can show a message in offline stat to unknown user that say: `you must Login in online stat first!`

for making better angularjs offline web application, i recommend to you this article: [Offline apps using Ionic Framework, PouchDB and AngularJS](https://medium.com/@pinkyBrayne/offline-apps-using-ionic-framework-pouchdb-and-angularjs-44070fe39cc0)